# Throws annotation is not recognised

Tags: scala, playframework, annotations

I am trying to indicate that a method can throw an exception. I use the throws annotation, but the compiler shows me a warning:

```
[warn] /root/playit/app/entities/game/GameRepository.scala:67: Tag '@throws(classOf[DatabaseException])' is not recognised
[warn]   /**
[warn]   ^
```

The code is the following:

```
/**
 * @throws(classOf[DatabaseException])
 */
def insert(game: Game): Long = {
   ...
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. The IDE says "Missing tag parameter". I am using Play 2.4 and IntelliJ IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the Scala [`@throws`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.throws) annotation with the Scaladoc `@throws`tag.

The annotation goes directly on the method and is actually compiled into bytecode (like the `throws` keyword in Java), the Scaladoc is turned into documentation (for example, under which circumstances the exception is thrown).

```
/**
 * @throws DatabaseException Banana banana.
 */
@throws(classOf[DatabaseException])
def insert(game: Game): Long = {
   ...
}
```

*Edited to add:*

This syntax combines both, and looks preferable to me:

```
@throws[DatabaseException]("Banana banana.")
def insert(game: Game): Long = {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think about that. I've seen two ways of writing it: @throws(classOf([Exception]) and @throws[Exception]("reason"). Can I use both?

Comment: Yes, they should both work. I've updated the answer.